# JavaScript Fade in, fadeout numbers also to center my images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I have:

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mixer').fadeIn(3000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('#mixer1').delay(2000).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(2000);
        $('#turntable').delay(2000).fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(1500);
        $('#turntable1').delay(2000).fadeIn(1500);
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#mixer, #mixer1, #turntable, #turntable1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50;
    right: 10;
    margin - left: auto;
}
```

Basically I just want it in the middle fade in and out to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Use callbacks

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#mixer').fadeIn(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();

    $('#mixer1').fadeIn(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut();

      ...  

    }, 3000);

  }, 3000);
});
```